# Prefix all requests in JSON Server with middleware

Tags: node.js, express, json-server

I'm using the JSON Server package (json-server) from https://github.com/typicode/json-server. I'd like to make the server prefix all requests with `/api/v2`. The documentation even gives an example how to do this with the following:

`server.use('/api', router)`

However I don't want to setup my own server instance but extend the default when running `json-server`.

Can I somehow use the above statement in a middleware?

Answer (score 3):

Since the router that `json-server` returns to you *is* an [Express router](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router).

First define all of your `/v1`, `/v2`, etc in its own routes file as show below:

```
// api-routes.js
const express = require('express')
const jsonServer = require('json-server')

const router = express.Router()
const server = jsonServer.create()
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()
const v1Router = jsonServer.router('db-v1.json')
const v2Router = jsonServer.router('db-v2.json')


router.use('/v1', v1Router)
router.use('/v2', v2Router)

module.exports = router
```

Then mount your API router onto `/api` like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const apiRoutes = require('./api-routes')

const app = express()
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)

// ...
```

Should now have `/api/v1` and `/api/v2`. Untested code above, but should give an idea what you need to do.