# Syntax for json-server middlewares

Tags: express, json-server

I am trying to use middleware in json-server, just to append specific properties to body response at specific routes. I have this working code:

```
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  switch (req.path) {
    case '/items':
      switch (req.method){
        case 'POST':
          req.body.dateCreated = Date.now();
          req.body.status = 0;
          break;

        case 'PUT':
          req.body.dateModified = Date.now();
          break;
      }
  }
  next();
});

server.use(router);
```

but I was wondering if there is a nicer syntax/way to install these overrides the express-way, ie. `server.method(path, cb)` - something like:

```
app.post('/items', (req, res, next) => {
  // my override
});
```

so that route parameters (such as `items/:id`) can be easily resolved?

Comment: I generally export middlewares as modules and import them to use w/ json-server. So then I have something like `server.use(middlewareModule)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, it seems that the router that json-server returns to you is an Express router (so you can apply similar patterns as Express middleware).

For example:

```js
server.use("/items", require("./customMiddleware1")); // all requests to /items
server.post("/items", require("./customMiddleware2")); // post requests to /items

server.use("/users", require("./customMiddleware3")); // all requests to /users
```

And then create the files for your middleware. For example, `customMiddleware2.js`:

```js
function customMiddleware2(req, res, next) {
    console.log("that was a post request!");
    next();
}

module.exports = customMiddleware2;
```

You may also find this answer useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562328/11298742